# Django add aggregate operation to a query result

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to do an aggregate operation between two tables using Django, my models are:

```
class Cusinetype(models.Model):
    hometype_en = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
    hometype_es = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cusinetype'

class Foodpreferences(models.Model):
    id_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_client')
    id_cusinetype = models.ForeignKey(Cusinetype, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_cusinetype')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'foodpreferences'
```

The query that I'm trying to build is:

```
SELECT 
    ct.id, 
    ct.hometype_en, 
    ct.hometype_es 
    , 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM foodpreferences fp 
        WHERE fp.id_cusinetype = ct.id AND fp.id_client = 3    ) > 0 ) selected
FROM
    Cusinetype ct
```

I'm trying to generate a model, to store the information of those tables in a single one query, but anything works.
Someone has an idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**serializers.py**

```
class PreferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    selected = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Cusinetype
        fields = ('id', 'trucktype_en', 'trucktype_es', 'selected')
```

**views.py**

```
    qs = Cusinetype.objects.filter().filter(active = True)
            qs = qs.annotate(    
                selected=Sum(Case(
                    When(foodpreferences__id_client=3, then=1),
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                ))

            )
        serializers = PreferencesSerializer(qs, many = True)
        return Response({ "result": serializers.data })
```

Comment: Result of this solution are correct, but the query uses much slower query than you expected in the SQL example. You read Foodpreferences of all clients. I recommend to use [Exists() subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries). The example is so similar, that it doesn't need more comments. It would be fine to put there a better solution and accept it.